# What is the correct spelling of the session token parameter for Google Places API requests?

Tags: google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

[The documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) for the session token for the Google Places API refers to the parameter as both `sessiontoken` and `session_token` throughout the document. Which one is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making a request with *both* `sessiontoken` and `session_token` parameters included results in:

```
{
    "error_message": "Invalid request. Only one of the 'sessiontoken' or 'session_token' parameters are allowed.",
    "predictions": [],
    "status": "INVALID_REQUEST"
}
```

So apparently either one is acceptable.